# Python: Configparser: Adding item to section deletes other items

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I have the following files:

`main.py`:

```
import configparser


config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.add_section('section 1')
config.set('section 1', 'item3', 'c')

with open('file.txt', 'w') as configFile:
    config.write(configFile)
```

`file.txt`:

```
[section 1]
item1 = a
item2 = b
```

When running main.py I want `item3 = c` to just be added to `section 1` without deleting any of the other items, however it results in the following `file.txt`:

```
[section 1]
item3 = c
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you add item3, try reading your existing file first!  Otherwise, you're just creating a brand new configuration that will not contain the contents of the file.  Also, I don't think you need to create the section, since it will be parsed when you read the existing file.

```
config.read('file.txt')
```

Comment: Kinda weird behaviour but that fixed it, thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  But it's not weird at all.  Your config object will not contain the items in the file unless you first read in the file.  When you open file.txt for writing, its existing contents are overwritten.  An important concept to understand!